# plot data on Geopandas matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas, fiona

i want to plot x and y from a csv file  in a geopandas graph but only the graph axis that shows up

```
import fiona
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axisartist.axislines import Subplot
import pandas as pd
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers["KML"] = "rw"
dfN = pd.read_csv ("nodes.txt",delimiter ="\\s+")
dfN.to_csv ("nodes.csv", index=None)
df = gpd.read_file("data.kml", driver="KML")
df=df.to_crs(epsg=32733)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfN ,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(dfN.X, dfN.Y))
dg=df.translate(433050,299)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.scatter(gdf.X, gdf.Y , zorder=1, alpha= 1, c='r', s=10)
dg.plot(ax=ax,zorder=0,color='white', edgecolor='black',aspect= 'equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe your CSV file is empty. Maybe `gpd` whatever that is was overwritten in a previous step. We don't know.

Comment: Note that your plot is not only plotting the y axis - it's just that your x axis looks like it covers a very small range while your y axis ranges from 0 to 1.6e7, and you use `ax.set_aspect('equal')` which forces them to be plotted on the same scale, so the x axis has a width roughly 1e-7 x height.

Answer (score 1):

- this is not a MWE so have sourced data from publicly available and have applied same transformations...
- plotting code can simplified, then it works.  using `plot()` on **geopandas** which includes *POINT* objects will produce a scatter

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import requests, io

# data sourcing generated two geopandas data frames,  let's replace to make MWE
df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
df=df.to_crs(epsg=32733)

dg = df.loc[df["geometry"].is_valid *df["iso_a3"].eq("GBR")].translate(433050,299)
dfN = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(requests.get("https://assets.nhs.uk/data/foi/Hospital.csv").text),
    sep="Č",engine="python",).loc[:,["OrganisationName","Latitude","Longitude"]].rename(columns={"Latitude":"Y","Longitude":"X"})

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfN ,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(dfN.X, dfN.Y))
gdf = gdf.set_crs("EPSG:4326").to_crs(epsg=32733)

# plotting code is simplified as:
ax = dg.plot(zorder=0,color='white', edgecolor='black',aspect= 'equal')
gdf.plot(ax=ax, zorder=1, alpha= 1, c='r', markersize=10)
```

#### output

- clearly within the defined CRS, plus one set of geometry has been transformed

[image]